# Why my condition is not working as expected?

Tags: vb.net

My condition was not effective what was the problem in that? Could anyone help me?

```
Public Class Form5

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim a As Integer
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            TextBox2.Text = ""
        End If

        a = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            TextBox2.Text = ""
        ElseIf (a < 4.9) Then
            TextBox2.Text = ("Little or No Damage")
        ElseIf (a <= 5 AndAlso a >= 5.5) Then
            TextBox2.Text = ("Some Damage")
        ElseIf (a <= 5.6 And a >= 6.5) Then
            TextBox2.Text = ("Serious Damage")
        ElseIf (a <= 6.6 And a >= 7.5) Then
            TextBox2.Text = ("Disaster")
        ElseIf (a > 7.5) Then
            TextBox2.Text = ("Catasthrope")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How can `a` be less than or equal to 5 *and* greater than or equal to 5.5 at the same time? (for example)

Comment: "lang po"? What exactly is this supposed to mean??

Comment: It seems you just mixed up `<=` and `>=`

Comment: For example @JonSkeet I input 5.4 in textbox1 then in textbox2 should show "somedamage"

Comment: @ShadowWizard don't mind it

Comment: @user3379407 it's the question title, I do mind. Is this supposed to be shortcut for "problem"? Never mind now, I edited myself to reflect real question here.

Comment: Why would it show that? After all, 5.4 isn't less than or equal to 5 *or* more than 5.5... (look *carefully* at your code)

Comment: Thanks guys. I get it now. Sorry for my english :) Take care

Answer (score 3):

You just mixed up `<=` and `>=`.

But it would be more readable and less error prone if you would use a `Select` instead, e.g.:

```
Select Case a
    Case Is < 4.9
        TextBox2.Text= "Little or No Damage"
    Case 5 To 5.5
        TextBox2.Text= "Some Damage"
    Case 5.6 To 6.5
        TextBox2.Text= "Serious Damage"
    Case 6.6 To 7.5
        TextBox2.Text= "Disaster"
    Case Is > 7.5
        TextBox2.Text= "Catasthrope"
End Select
```

Comment: tnx I get it. Godbless

Comment: @user3379407 understanding SO rules, you should mark this answer as accepted. a 'Thankyou' are not welcome here.